# html/asp.net formatting , display data using text boxes datagrid and a combination of things

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

This might be a weird question, but I know what I'm looking for i just don't know what it's called.

I've created a few textboxes with no borders and some labels that go next to them.  And in each of these text boxes contains some part of data from a Datatable, in these textboxes is a distinct piece of data from the returned rows.

Below all of that is a DataColumn that displays the details of all the rows for that particular item.

For the life of me, I cannot get this setup to look visually appealing.  The textboxes aren't on the same column, the datarow is to far apart.  Is there a control I'm looking for that would help me out?  Instead of creating each element individually?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words (even if it looks bad)  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx)? For the child records, you seem to want either a GridView or a ListView.